# Packages organization in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, plsqldeveloper

We are working with Packages in PL/SQL and I want to know if we can work in a similar way to. For instance, Java, where you can create a Package into another like directories. For instance:

```
myapplication.account.balance
```

So, we can work with packages with the same name but in different subpackages.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as "nested packages".

One way to have "nested packages" would be to just introduce your own package separator like `$`. But then again, you'd hit the 30 character limit, which applies to any kind of object name, really fast.

My advice is to not try emulating "nested packages" in Oracle. Just stick to flat packages, give them proper names and maybe, just maybe give them a prefix like `PAC_` to avoid conflicts with other objects, because <strike>Oracle doesn't separate object types into namespaces</strike> some object types like packages and tables share the same namespace (see [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) for details).

Comment: It doesn't take away from the point you are making, but Oracle does separate some object types into namespaces; [see object naming rule 8](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223).

Answer (score 1):

You can place your packages in different `SCHEMA`. It is not truly "nested packages", but it can help you if you want to work with different packages which have same names.

For example, you can create two schemas  `research_department` and `production_department`. In each schema you can create packages with same name e.g. `accountant_service` and in each packages we can create procedures `calc_salary()`.

Then you can call procedures using a schema name:
`research_department.accountant_service.calc_salary()`
`production_department.accountant_service.calc_salary()`

Or you can use only package and procedure name: `accountant_service.calc_salary()`. In this case will be executed procedure from current schema

Or you can use only procedure name (inside package):
`calc_salary()`. In this case will be executed procedure from current package.

Answer (score 0):

In our company we use different schemata, prefixes and postfixes.
We have more than 100 packages and it works very good.

e.g. myappl1.acnt_balance